# HTML table without grey border lines in one codelisting including CSS elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need a table-structure in HTML, which i could insert in a HTML-widget for WordPress. i have no chance to use a separate CSS-file for definitions. Border=0 doesn't work. i always get grey line in the cells.

I try to set border color to white, because the template has a white background. But the global CSS-definitions overwrite that i think.

```html
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not seeing border with this code, can you please provide codepen url ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put border:0 into the "style" attribute so that it becomes more important than external CSS, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;border:0" cellpadding="2"
cellspacing="2">
</head>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</html>
```

Comment: The result is the same. It looks like the screenshot [link](https://skriptologe.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/table-border-grey.png). "border:0" doesn´t mean no line i think. May be it´s possible to set the bordercolor white, but i don´t know how.

Comment: Well I tried it and when I put it in "style" it worked... But there's a line in the middle so it's not the border of the table but the border of <td>... Try to set td borders to 0 too!

Comment: That´s it! Thanky you!